# adobe flash cs5 how to move the container & childrens

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

So how can I craete a container for a tank(without code as3) to move the tank(using as3 like tank.x += tankSpeed) itself and at the same time all his parts(wheels, turrel, other stuff), because i don't want to move all the parts independently in each frame, for example rotating the turrel and at the same time move the container of the tank, I didn't found in adobe flash cs5 how to add shapes(rectangles, circles...) to some main container and give it some object name and then get something like this in the code(as3):

```
container //get the container itself

container.child1

container.child2
```

if it possible of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `MovieClip` in CS5, put it on the stage, and give it the instance name `tank`. Inside that `MovieClip` draw your tank but put each of the moving parts into `MovieClips` of their own each with a unique instance name, say `wheel_1`, `wheel_2`, `turret`, `other_thing`.

Now you can manipulate the parts of your tank independently from code on the main timeline like this:

```
tank.wheel_1.play();
tank.turret.stop();
tank.wheel_2.gotoAndPlay('reverse');
```

A simple routine to move the tank would look something like this (untested):

```
var speed = 10;

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);

// Execute on each frame
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    tank.x += speed;
}
```

Comment: hmmmm yes that works fine, i've created an animation an gived him a object name, so if i write tank.stop() - the animation will stop successfully, but if i write tank.body.stop() - it don't work, there are 2 object names, the movieClip object name AND the name of the animation itself, i don't know how to stop animating a specific part, not all the parts, if i write tank.animObjectName.stop() - i get an error

Comment: Make sure the moving parts all have instance names and are accessible on every frame of your tank MovieClip.